# What happens with this method name/local variable mixing?

Tags: ruby

I have spotted a method in some code that does the following :

```
def method1
  method1 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]
  return method1.uniq!
end
```

How does ruby handle this? I know this is bad code, but how does the ruby know what to do with 'method1.uniq!' ? Should it use the method, or the local variable?

Thanks

Comment: Beside your question: `method1.uniq!` is no good idea here. `uniq` would be better. Reason: `method1 = [1, 2,3, 4, 5]; method1.uniq!` results in `nil`, because `uniq!` did not find duplicates.

Comment: I don't think that's bad code. We often need to return something and the ideal name for that return value is usually the method's name itself. Not bad as long as you know that ruby looks for local variables first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open a ruby session in a terminal (`irb`), type in the code in your question, and see the results yourself.

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.1.0)
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > def derp
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002?>   derp = [1,2,3,3,3]
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :003?>   derp.uniq
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :004?>   end
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :005 > derp
 => [1, 2, 3]
```

To answer your question, ruby knows the difference between the method `derp` and the local variable within its scope `derp`.

Comment: Ruby will look for local variables first, then for methods. If you were trying to call the method `derp` after having defined a variable of the same name, you could do `self.derp` to make sure the method was called instead.

Comment: Yeah I know what the codes return, wondered how Ruby handled it internally. It seems that my Ruby 1.8.7 gets confused and consume a LOT of memory to get the result, while 1.9.2 has no problem.

Comment: @Emily Thanks for the clarification. Any idea about the 1.8.7 vs 1.9.2 difference on that?

Comment: What is your evidence for it "getting confused and using a lot of memory"?

Comment: @Karl looking at the server memory usage when this methods get executed... it goes from around 50mb of RAM to about 750.

Answer (score 0):

If you do `defined?(method1)` it will tell you that there is a local variable method1 and if you do `defined?(method1())` it will say that there is a method `method1`.

The similarity in syntax between local variables and methods means that when you call a setter method within an object, you have to do `self.foo = 42` .