# method's local variable with same name as another method

Tags: ruby

I was trying to figure out how Ruby handles local variables that have the same names as the methods in `self` class, and found a behavior that I do not understand:

```
class A
  def val
    10
  end

  def test
    val = val
  end
end

p A.new.test
```

this code prints `nil`. why?!

Comment: The method `val` is a red herring. You're never actually calling it.

Comment: Similar for the method and a variable inside it with the same name: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174019/what-happens-with-this-method-name-local-variable-mixing, variable outside: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741582/method-and-variable-name-is-the-same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the local variable is declared as soon as it's enunciated. In ruby the lookup is first to look for a local variable, if it exists it's used, and if not it looks for a method. This would mean that val = val declares the first val as local and the left-hand val then matches it (not sure about it I should check the [ruby under microscope](http://patshaughnessy.net/ruby-under-a-microscope) to be sure)

If you try

```
class A
  def val
    10
  end

  def test
    back = []
    x = val
    back << x
    val = x + 1
    back << val
    x = val
    back << x
  end
end

p A.new.test
```

then all is good, it prints [10, 11, 11] which means the first x = val calls the method, the second calls the local variable, presumably.

Comment: thanks. this is a reasonable explanation. it also explains why it does not raise an exception in `val = val`.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers explain everything fine I just want to point readers with the same problem to the [official documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variables+and+Methods) about this.

> ### [Local Variables and Methods](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variables+and+Methods)
>
> In Ruby local variable names and method names are nearly identical. If you have not assigned to one of these ambiguous names ruby will assume you wish to call a method. Once you have assigned to the name ruby will assume you wish to reference a local variable.
>
> The local variable is created when the parser encounters the assignment, not when the assignment occurs:
>
> ```
> a = 0 if false # does not assign to a
>
> p local_variables # prints [:a]
>
> p a # prints nil
> ```
>
> The similarity between method and local variable names can lead to confusing code, for example:
>
> ```
> def big_calculation
>   42 # pretend this takes a long time
> end
>
> big_calculation = big_calculation()
> ```
>
> Now any reference to `big_calculation` is considered a local variable and will be cached. To call the method, use `self.big_calculation`.
>
> You can force a method call by using empty argument parentheses as shown above or by using an explicit receiver like `self`. Using an explicit receiver may raise a [`NameError`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/NameError.html) if the method's visibility is not public or the receiver is the literal `self`.
>
> Another commonly confusing case is when using a modifier `if`:
>
> ```
> p a if a = 0.zero?
> ```
>
> Rather than printing “true” you receive a [NameError](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/NameError.html), “undefined local variable or method `a'”. Since ruby parses the bare `a` left of the `if` first and has not yet seen an assignment to `a` it assumes you wish to call a method. Ruby then sees the assignment to `a` and will assume you are referencing a local method.
>
> The confusion comes from the out-of-order execution of the expression. First the local variable is assigned-to then you attempt to call a nonexistent method.

Comment: Note that *"Using an explicit receiver may raise a `NameError` if the method's visibility is not public"* is no longer an issue. Since [Ruby 2.7](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/25/ruby-2-7-0-released/) calling private methods using `self.big_calculation` is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

This should be split into two questions:

1. When you have `a = a`, what is evaluated first? If you do `echo 'p a = a' | ruby`, you get `nil`, not undefined exception, so the definition comes first.
2. What happens when a local variable has the same names as a method? Answer: method becomes invisible unless you use `self.`

Answer (score 0):

It's `nil` because `val` is the method you're trying to pass around and you're not calling `val` anywhere and it's overriding itself. You're stuck in a loop basically.

At the end of each function is an implicit return which returs the last value and if it has no value to return Ruby returns `nil` but you were perhaps expecting a function?

This is similar in Python where a function without a return always returns `None`.

This can be solved by turning the left hand `val` into a instance property with the `@` connotation.

I'm guessing you want it to print `10` using the `val()` method?

```
def test
    @val = val()
end

puts A.new.test
```

Below is also valid:

```
def test
    val = self.val() #but this will produce the same as above to no real benefit.
end
```

The key being that you must call the `val` method in order for the `val` variable to get the value.

Comment: thank you. I would not say that I am stuck in a loop because the program terminates. I was expecting `10`, not a function. Definitely this has something to do with parentheses. If my `test` method just has one line `val` then it returns `10`. But the confusing part for me was that the assignment resulted in `val` being `nil`.

Comment: Not really, it has more to do with the fact that you're trying to tell Ruby that `val` is itself. Which results in a loop where Ruby can't figure out what you want.

Comment: there is no loop. the program terminates. I am confused.