# Weird behavior of params hash in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

After doing a lot of debugging, I have isolated a problem but I cannot explain it. Here is a bit of Sinatra Code:

```
post '/modify' do

# at this point params contains the action key as I expect it.

  puts "1: action is #{params["action"]}"
  if (params["action"] == "del")
    puts "#{params}" 
    puts "delete"
  end

# At this point params still contains the "action" key as I expect it
  puts "2: action is #{params["action"]}"
  if (params["action"] == 'create') 
    puts "#{params}" 
    puts "create"

#### THE NEXT LINE IS THE PROBLEM!
    params = { :n => @number }
    redirect '/'
  end

# At this point params is nil
  puts "3: ????? #{params}"
  foo = params["action"]
  #puts "3: action is #{params["action"]}"
  if (foo == "refresh")
    puts "***: #{params}"
    redirect '/'
  end
  puts "3: #{params}"
  puts "3: action is #{params["action"]}"
end
```

This code as written, when params["action"] is not equal to del or create, will give an error that [] is not valid on a nil value.

I conclude that by assigning a value to params inside a conditional that IS NOT EXECUTED the params hash (which is really a method from Sinatra) becomes nil.

Even if there was something with variable scoping in Ruby that doesn't recognize a if/then as a new scope, still that line is not executed.

Can you see it?

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50183613/1086121). `params` starts off being [a method](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L78), but then the parser finds that you declare a variable with the same name (even though it never actually executes the assignment to it), and creates the `params` variable, which is chosen in preference to the `params` method.

Comment: Another case of using a reserved word for a parameter, then blowing the mind of the interpreter.

Comment: @canton7 great information. I never knew that. I wonder if that's a quirk of MRI or is it part of the language spec? Anyway, you have the correct answer. I learned something subtle but useful! if you wish to post it as an answer I would mark it as correct asap!

Comment: @3limin4t0r beat me to it. Accept theirs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to confuse the method `params` for the local variable `params`.

Let's take a look at a simplified example:

```rb
def params
  {"action" => "some-action"}
end

# the line below refers to the method #params
p params # {"action" => "some-action"}

# the variable params is created, but not assigned
params = {n: 1} if false

# any further reference to params will use the variable
p params # nil
```

If you now have the question "why is the variable created?" the simple answer is: Because the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variables+and+Methods) says so.

> The local variable is created when the parser encounters the
>   assignment, not when the assignment occurs:
>
> ```
> a = 0 if false # does not assign to a
>
> p local_variables # prints [:a]
>
> p a # prints nil
> ```

To solve your issue either use the `#params=` setter (assuming there is one) or retrieve the method result to a variable to start with, this way all references to `params` refer to the variable.

```rb
# assign using the setter method
self.params = { :n => @number }

# extract the contents to a variable at the start
# of the `post '/modify' do` block
params = self.params # or params()
```

Comment: Great answers! Do we ageee that that this is. ‘Bug’ in the ruby language spec?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to brush up on HTML's stateless nature in "[Why is  HTTP protocol called stateless protocol?](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-HTTP-protocol-called-stateless-protocol#:~:text=)" .

The `params` variable you're accessing is built up from the query parameters of your inbound request. When you execute a redirect you're going to a new URL and you have to build the query parameters into the URL. That way, on the other side of the redirect, it can be rebuilt into the `params` hash you're expecting. See "Browser Redirect" in Sinatra's "[Getting Started](http://sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Browser%20Redirect)" for more info.

Think of a redirect as a giant wall you're about to climb. If you want to have something that you currently have on your side of the wall when you get to the other side of the wall, you have to take it with you when you climb the wall.

Comment: See "[Don't use "click here" as link text](https://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere)". Prove something more useful when linking; The title of the page is a decent starting point.

Comment: Sorry but while your statement is true it is not relevant to my question. Check out the comment above by @cantonz